# LaTeX Table to Standalone?

Tags: tables, formatting, pdf, standalone, latex-to-word

I have a relatively complicated table with a lot of manual adjustments to the column widths and spacing that I am trying to convert to a `standalone` pdf (for the purpose of ultimately inserting it into a Word Doc). The original table text is below:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X  >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X }
\hline
\hline
\vspace{1mm}
 & Initiate conflict \\
\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
First = female                      & $-0.08$      \\
                                            & $(0.05)$     \\
Second = prefer not to say         & $-0.21$      \\
                                            & $(0.18)$     \\
Third = non-binary/non-conforming  & $-0.18$      \\
                                            & $(0.12)$     \\
(Intercept)                                 & $0.35^{***}$ \\
                                            & $(0.03)$     \\
\hline
R$^2$                                       & $0.01$       \\
Adj. R$^2$                                  & $0.01$       \\
Num. obs.                                   & $404$        \\
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$; $^{**}p<0.01$; $^{*}p<0.05$}}
\end{tabularx} \\
\parbox{11cm}{\caption{Random caption inserted as a placeholder for what I am actually going to say, which will be a sentence or two long in the end I think.}}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Any guidance on how to successfully make this work in a document type `standalone` would be greatly appreciated. Alternatively, if there is an easier way to put such a table into a Word Doc, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: The site guidelines recommend waiting several hours, and better yet a day or two, before "accepting" a particular answer. For by rapidly accepting the first answer that comes along, you're actually discouraging others from posting additional, and possibly better, answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that using a `tabularx` environment with two equally wide columns and some ensuing line-breaks in the first column generates a good layout. I'd go with a basic `tabular` environment, use `l` for the first column, and align the numbers in the second column. To force the width of the legend to be the same as the `tabular` material above it, I suggest you employ a `threeparttable` wrapper.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l d{2.3} @{}}
\toprule
 & \mc{Initiate conflict} \\
\midrule
First = female                     & -0.08      \\
                                   & (0.05)     \\
Second = prefer not to say         & -0.21      \\
                                   & (0.18)     \\
Third = non-binary/non-conforming  & -0.18      \\
                                   & (0.12)     \\
(Intercept)                        & 0.35^{***} \\
                                   & (0.03)     \\
\addlinespace
R$^2$                              & 0.01       \\
Adj.\ R$^2$                        & 0.01       \\
Num.\ obs.                         & \mc{404}   \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\scriptsize $^{***}\ p<0.001$; $^{**}\ p<0.01$; $^{*}\ p<0.05$} 
\end{tabular}

Random caption inserted as a placeholder for what I am actually going to say, which will be a sentence or two long in the end I think.
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

As compliment to nice @Mico answer (+1), with use of the `tabularray` package, i.e. with its `talltblr` environment which is equivalent to classic `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
    \SetTblrStyle{remark}{font=\scriptsize}


\begin{document}

\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Caption text},
  label = {tab:statistic},
remark{Note} = {$^{***}\ p<0.001$; $^{**}\ p<0.01$; $^{*}\ p<0.05$}
                ]{width=0.7\linewidth,      % see @John Kormylo comment 
                  colspec  = {X[l] Q[c, si={table-format=-1.2{$^{***}$},
                                            input-open-uncertainty =,
                                            input-close-uncertainty=,
                                            table-align-text-before=false}]},
                  row{1,Z} = {guard},
                  row{2-X} = {rowsep=0pt},
                  row{2}   = {abovesep=2pt},
                  row{even[3-X]} = {abovesep=1ex},
                  cell{even[1-W]}{1} = {r=2}{h},    % see manual,  page 14
                  row{X-Z} = {rowsep=1pt},
                }
    \toprule
                                    &   Initiate conflict   \\
    \midrule
First = female                      & -0.08                 \\
                                    & (0.05)                \\
Second = prefer not to say          & -0.21                 \\
                                    & (0.18)                \\
Third = non-binary/ non-conforming  & -0.18                 \\
                                    & (0.12)                \\
(Intercept)                         & 0.35\TblrNote{***}    \\
                                    & (0.03)                \\
    \specialrule{dashed, fg=gray}{3pt}{3pt}
R$^2$                               & 0.01                  \\
Adj.\ R$^2$                         & 0.01                  \\
Number of observations              & 404                   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** considered is @Mico comment.

Comment: +1: It's cool that new table packages are being made! Thanks for showing me the tabularray package.

Comment: +1. Two minor issues. (a) The vertical distance between `\midrule` and the `First = female` row seems quite small. Same for `\midrule[dashed, fg=gray]` and the subsequent row. (b) One could replace `non-binary/ non` with `non-binary\slash non`; that way, the line break after "non-binary/" could dissappear without creating an unnecessary gap if the overall width is increased to, say, `0.75\textwidth`.

Comment: @Mico, thanky ou very much for comments. I consider most of yours suggestion. Only I had problem with ˛slash. I try to see how works multirow cells, but I hag unexpected problem with hyphenation. So far I left existed solution for further investigation of hyphenation of this composed long word.

Answer (score 5):

looking for something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx} % add tabularx package
\usepackage{booktabs} % add booktabs package for nicer horizontal rules
\begin{document}
%   \begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        & Initiate conflict \\
        \midrule
        First = female & $-0.08$ \\
        & $(0.05)$ \\
        Second = prefer not to say & $-0.21$ \\
        & $(0.18)$ \\
        Third = non-binary/non-conforming & $-0.18$ \\
        & $(0.12)$ \\
        (Intercept) & $0.35^{***}$ \\
        & $(0.03)$ \\
        \midrule
        R$^2$ & $0.01$ \\
        Adj. R$^2$ & $0.01$ \\
        Num. obs. & $404$ \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
%   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

the caption you can insert later in the word doc

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I couldn't get the caption to work, but this solution makes sense and is equally as simple. Thank you!

Comment: I've take the liberty of adding a screenshot that's produced by your code. The fact that you're allowing line breaks in the first column has unfortunate is leading to an unfortunate bunching of the material in the second column. I think one would be better off using a `tabular` environment with column types `l` and `r`.

Comment: It is interesting that standalone sets \textwidth=345pt by default (same value ast [class=article]).  I seem to recall it being much larger (\maxdimen}.

Answer (score 5):

I would personally combine values with uncertainties in one line. I find it clearer to read. Also since `siunitx` parses uncertainties this way, it's possible to use an alternative format if you add `separate-uncertainty` to settings.

The code below also employ `threeparttable` (inpsired by [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682065/31283)'s answer) in order to stack two separate tables and maintain centred alignment where uncertainties are not included.

```latex
\documentclass[margin=2.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  uncertainty-mode=full,
  uncertainty-separator=\,,
  table-column-width=2.4cm,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{tabular}{p{6cm} S[table-format=-1.2(1)]}
    \toprule
    & {\clap{Initiate conflict}} \\
    \midrule
    First = female                    & -0.08(0.05) \\
    Second = prefer not to say        & -0.21(0.18) \\
    Third = non-binary/non-conforming & -0.18(0.12) \\
    (Intercept)                       &  0.35(0.03)$^{***}$ \\
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{\dimexpr6pt-\lineskip}%
  \begin{tabular}{p{6cm} S[table-format=-1.2]}
    R$^2$                             & 0.01 \\
    Adj. R$^2$                        & 0.01 \\
    Num. obs.                         & {$\phantom{-}404$} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$; $^{**}p<0.01$; $^{*}p<0.05$}}
  \end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

[image]